# Error specifying the file path in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python and do not know it very well.
I want modified the online code to convert my image data to lmdb form.

I given the root of my src and dst like below:
paths_src = 'F:\caffe-windows\caffe-windows\data\sift-flow\test\'
path_dst = 'F:\caffe-windows\caffe-windows\data\sift-flow\testlmdb'

but after i run the code I got a error. it seem that my path is wrong? can anyone help? I also attach the code.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from scipy import io
import lmdb
import caffe
from PIL import Image

NUM_IDX_DIGITS = 10
IDX_FMT = '{:0>%d' % NUM_IDX_DIGITS + 'd}'

print '1111'

paths_src = 'F:\\caffe-windows\\caffe-windows\\data\\sift-flow\\test\\'
path_dst = 'F:\\caffe-windows\\caffe-windows\\data\\sift-flow\\testlmdb'

print '2222'

def img_to_lmdb(paths_src,path_dst):
    in_db = lmdb.open(path_dst, map_size=int(1e9))
    with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:
        for in_idx, in_ in enumerate(paths_src):
            print 'img:::'+str(in_)
            # load image:
            # - as np.uint8 {0, ..., 255}
            # - in BGR (switch from RGB)
            # - in Channel x Height x Width order (switch from H x W x C)
            im = np.array(Image.open(in_)) # or load whatever ndarray you need
            im = im[:,:,::-1]
            im = im.transpose((2,0,1))
            im_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(im)
            in_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx), im_dat.SerializeToString())
    in_db.close()



img_to_lmdb(paths_src,path_dst)
print '3333'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this library but your problem starts in this line-
`for in_idx, in_ in enumerate(paths_src):`

because paths_src is a string, which is iterable, the builtin function enumerate simply goes through each one of the characters in that string, so the first item would be the letter 'F' and not the entire path.
What you should do is define paths_src as a list. so instead of:

```
paths_src = 'F:\\caffe-windows\\caffe-windows\\data\\sift-flow\\test\\'
```

you should do:

```
paths_src = ['F:\\caffe-windows\\caffe-windows\\data\\sift-flow\\test\\']
```

Hope I was helpful.

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. I tried your suggestion but get a new error: Filesystem path must be Unicode or bytes..

Comment: Could you please copy the stacktrace?(P.S. you should keep the path in a list like I said, this is simply another error we need to figure out.)

Comment: so I should put all my image path in a list just like a vector in c++? Im totally new to python so..no idea how to do that... I will try later thank you for the help!